# Github: Failed to add secret. Please try again

Tags: github, amazon-iam, github-actions

I just created a IAM User in AWS and am now wanting to add the access key ID and the secret access key to my forked Github project for use in GitHub actions

I use the same name as defined in my workflow yml for GitHub actions, and enter the text copied from IAM, and I get this error with no further text:

Failed to add secret. Please try again.

Do you know what may cause this?

Comment: Was the internet correction interrupted? Is there an error in the developer tools? Is GitHub Actions enabled in that repository?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Safari. The console showed JS errors:
"Unrecognized Content-Security-Policy directive 'worker-src'"
...

Setting the secret through Chrome worked though.